# chmod: changing permissions of directory which is Read-only file system

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod

Locate the directory's `importfromwp` mount point.

```
df  /home/debian/mydoc/source/importfromwp
Filesystem     1K-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb3       30719996 434000  30285996   2% /mnt/shared
```

Content in fstab:

```
cat /etc/fstab |grep  shared
UUID=AAB278C8B2789B11   /mnt/shared  ntfs-3g rw,user,auto,fmask=0111,dmask=0022,permissions  0 0
```

I want to chmod on the directory.

```
sudo chmod -R 777  /home/debian/mydoc/source/importfromwp
chmod: changing permissions of xxxxx: Read-only file system
chmod: changing permissions of yyyyy: Read-only file system
```

How to chmod on the directory ?

```
fgrep /mnt/shared /proc/mounts
/dev/sdb3 /mnt/shared fuseblk ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
```

Comment: Does `fgrep /mnt/shared /proc/mounts` (kernel view, the only one that matters) also tell it's rw?

Comment: Why are you trying to set all files as executable? Are you sure you want `777` there? And why are you trying to change permissions on an NTFS filesystem? That uses a different permissions system. Could you explain what the eventual goal is here? I think you may be going about it in the wrong way.

Comment: @terdon the `permissions` option actually allows chmod to work in a posix-like manner (I'm not sure it's compatible with fmask/dmask though).

Comment: So from your results, it appears the filesystem failed to be mounted read-write (even if that was the intention in the configuration). If the chmod was an attempt to overcome this problem, fine, else also check terdon's comment. Anyway your issue is now about why it was mounted read-only. There are probably a lot of possible reasons. `dmesg` after unmounting and mounting again might help